# Dependency Injection in XAML (WPF)

Tags: xaml, dependency-injection

I am creating a new WPF project and we use Microsoft Unity as DI.

I am having a user control which is calling a 3rd party service.

So now how to inject dependency from the main window XAML for the usercontrol.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the service locator pattern. I use it with Unity as a DI.

```
internal class ServiceLocator
{
    [...]
    public MainViewModel Main { get { return container.Resolve<MainViewModel>(); } }
}
```

You can intantiate your class the way you want (DI or not, the class initializes the DI etc...).

In your App.xaml

```
<Application.Resources>
        <vm:ServiceLocator x:Key="Locator"/>
    </Application.Resources>
```

And now, you can set your datacontext

```
DataContext="{Binding Main, Source={StaticResource Locator}}"
```

Edit:

I found another way of doing it (among other):
Take a look at [this article](http://rachel53461.wordpress.com/2011/05/28/switching-between-viewsusercontrols-using-mvvm/). In the command, you can resolve your viewmodel as you like.